# Errors installing wireless driver

Tags: wireless, compiling

I have a wireless dongle and I'm attempting to install their Linux drivers [from here](http://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_n150/ew-7811un).

When I run `install.sh` (I only have the CLI), I get these errors. How can I get this working? This is a 64bit machine.

```
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: In function ârtw_proc_init_oneâ:
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:3: error: implicit declaration of function âcreate_proc_entryâ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
   ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:313:11: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   rtw_proc=create_proc_entry(rtw_proc_name, S_IFDIR, init_net.proc_net);
           ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:320:3: error: implicit declaration of function âcreate_proc_read_entryâ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("ver_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, rtw_proc, proc_get_drv_version, dev);
   ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:320:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("ver_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO, rtw_proc, proc_get_drv_version, dev);
         ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:326:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("log_level", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:332:8: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   entry->write_proc = proc_set_log_level;
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:348:21: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   padapter->dir_dev = create_proc_entry(dev->name,
                     ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:379:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("write_reg", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:385:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_write_reg;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:387:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("read_reg", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:393:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_read_reg;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:396:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("fwstate", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:404:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("sec_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:412:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mlmext_state", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:420:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("qos_option", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:427:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ht_option", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:434:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:441:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ap_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:448:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("adapter_state", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:455:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("trx_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:462:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:469:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:476:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("mac_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:483:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:490:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:497:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("bb_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:504:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump1", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:511:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump2", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:520:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump3", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:527:9: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   entry = create_proc_read_entry("rf_reg_dump4", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
         ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:537:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("all_sta_info", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:555:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("best_channel", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:561:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_best_channel;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:564:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rx_signal", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:570:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_signal;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:572:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ht_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:578:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_ht_enable;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:580:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("cbw40_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:586:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_cbw40_enable;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:588:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("ampdu_enable", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:594:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_ampdu_enable;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:596:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rx_stbc", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:602:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rx_stbc;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:605:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("path_rssi", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:608:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("vid", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:615:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("pid", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:622:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("rssi_disp", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:628:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_rssi_disp;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:631:8: warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
  entry = create_proc_read_entry("sreset", S_IFREG | S_IRUGO,
        ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:637:7: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
  entry->write_proc = proc_set_sreset;
       ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c: At top level:
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  .ndo_select_queue = rtw_select_queue,
  ^
/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.c:999:2: warning: (near initialization for ârtw_netdev_ops.ndo_select_queueâ) [enabled by default]
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/os_dep/linux/os_intfs.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/zeno/RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911/driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.13.0-32-generic'
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Or is there a .deb package I can get somewhere?

Answer (score 7):

I got this working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 (Kernel 3.13.0-35-generic), which seems to be similar to what you are running.

You will need to make some minor modifications to the driver source files. That means you cannot use the install.sh script as that will always unzip the driver ZIP and overwrite whatever changes you make.

Run these commands as root

Go to the driver directory `driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911`

```
# cd driver/rtl8188C_8192C_usb_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911
```

Change the `Makefile` and `include/autoconf.h` according to the following diffs (essentially comment out the lines with `EXTRA_CFLAGS` / `CONFIG_DEBUG_RTL819X` / `CONFIG_PROC_DEBUG` / `DBG_CONFIG_ERROR_DETECT`)

```
diff -pru rtl8192cu/Makefile rtl8192cu.new/Makefile
--- rtl8192cu/Makefile  2013-09-11 05:56:55.000000000 +0200
+++ rtl8192cu.new/Makefile      2013-12-06 16:09:37.000000000 +0100
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 EXTRA_CFLAGS += $(USER_EXTRA_CFLAGS)
-EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O1
+#EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O1
 #EXTRA_CFLAGS += -O3
 #EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wall
 #EXTRA_CFLAGS += -Wextra
```

and

```
diff -pru rtl8192cu/include/autoconf.h rtl8192cu.new/include/autoconf.h
--- rtl8192cu/include/autoconf.h        2013-09-11 05:56:55.000000000 +0200
+++ rtl8192cu.new/include/autoconf.h    2013-12-06 16:09:37.000000000 +0100
@@ -296,9 +296,9 @@
 //#define CONFIG_DEBUG_RTL871X

 #define DBG    0
-#define CONFIG_DEBUG_RTL819X
+//#define CONFIG_DEBUG_RTL819X

-#define CONFIG_PROC_DEBUG      1
+//#define CONFIG_PROC_DEBUG    1

 //#define DBG_IO
 //#define DBG_DELAY_OS
@@ -324,7 +324,7 @@

 //#define DBG_MEMORY_LEAK      1

-#define DBG_CONFIG_ERROR_DETECT
+//#define DBG_CONFIG_ERROR_DETECT
 //#define DBG_CONFIG_ERROR_RESET

 //TX use 1 urb
```

Now run:

```
# make
```

and

```
# make install
```

This will install a module called `8192cu`. 
Make sure you blacklist the default drivers that ship with the kernel:

Add this to /etc/modprobe.d/modprobe.conf (or create a /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-8192cu.conf file)

```
blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist rtl8192c_common
blacklist rtlwifi
```

Got this working thanks to the post of guanx [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/sporadic-internet-access-with-wireless-usb-adapter-4175486756/page2.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all insert your dongle in USB port. Now, wait for a while(actually just 8-10 seconds).

Now go to the panel and click on the network icon there. Select `Enable Mobile Broadband` there and after that all you need to do is select your mobile partner and other things. If your mobile partners name or **APN(ACCESS POINT NAME)** isn't available there, you'll need to search for your network service provider's access point name.

After you are done with all these steps you should be able to see your network's name in the network indicator of the Ubuntu panel. And you should be able to use your laptop as a hotspot as well.

This trick won't work for receiving messages from your network provider. It's just an alternative for the time being. You'll need to install Dongle's Software and for that you should follow the instructions provided in the software package from the vendor (there should be a **READ ME** file somewhere).

Comment: I don't have a GUI. Can you detail these for CLI?

Comment: Well I really can't help you then, coz I've never used a CL interface. Some other guy who has a better reputation then mine might help you out with this.