# wifi 8192cu tl-wn823n disabled

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, drivers, realtek

My laptop wifi is broken, so I bought a usb wifi card TL-WN823N(rtl8192cu module). (I know linux but I'm really new to linux drivers things.)

Since I'm using "14.04.2 LTS, Trusty Tahr", I need to install the driver myself. I downloaded the driver from [Realtek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=21&PFid=48&Level=5&Conn=4&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false&Downloads=true#2772), compiled and installed it. During that I met some compilation error and solved according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/505969/errors-installing-wireless-driver). And `reboot`.

Now the `wlan1` seems **DISABLED** .

```
cipher@Joy:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  ...
  *-network DISABLED
      description: Wireless interface
      product: Wireless 7260
      vendor: Intel Corporation
      physical id: 0
      bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
      logical name: wlan0
      version: 6b
      serial: 28:b2:bd:a3:76:7c
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 33MHz
      capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
      configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.16.0-30-generic firmware=25.228.9.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
      resources: irq:65 memory:f1400000-f1401fff
  *-network DISABLED                  # This is the usb wifi card.
   description: Wireless interface
   physical id: 3
   bus info: usb@2:1
   logical name: wlan1
   serial: 24:24:20:4e:49:43
   capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8192cu multicast=yes wireless=unassociated
```

When I tried to get it up manually:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ sudo ifconfig wlan1 up
SIOCSIFFLAGS: Operation not permitted
```

What are the proper reasons to get this? How can I get it up?

Here are some info about the current state:

Output of `lsmod`:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ lsmod | grep 8192
8192cu                527333  0
```

module depends:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ grep "8192cu" /lib/modules/3.16.0-30-generic/modules.dep
kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192cu/rtl8192cu.ko: kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl_usb.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtlwifi.ko kernel/drivers/net/wireless/rtlwifi/rtl8192c/rtl8192c-common.ko kernel/net/mac80211/mac80211.ko kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
updates/dkms/8192cu.ko:
```

Some output of `lspci`:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ lspci
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS5227 PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Output of `rfkill`:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ sudo rfkill list all
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
     Soft blocked: yes
     Hard blocked: no
```

I think it's the device of the system wifi card.
The usb card seems missing from `rfkill`.

Some output of `iwconfig`:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ iwconfig
wlan1     unassociated  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Auto  Frequency=2.412 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

system modules:

```
cipher@Joy:~$ cat /etc/modules
lp
rtc
# rtl8192cu
8192cu
```

blacklist about rtl8192cu:

```
cipher@Joy:/etc/modprobe.d$ grep 8192 * 
blacklist-8192cu.conf:blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist-8192cu.conf:blacklist rtl8192c_common
blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf:## This file ships with the rtl8192-fixes DKMS module.
blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf:blacklist rtl8192cu
blacklist-native-rtl8192.conf:blacklist rtl8192c_common
```

I've tried most posts about installing wireless drivers from google, and they brought me to the current situation.

I think I'm almost get the usb wifi card work, but how to get this continue: *get the wlan1 up ?*

Any experts can give any hints? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you include the result of `rfkill list all`

Comment: @Jeremy31 already updated. I think the usb card is not displayed in `rfkill`.

Comment: What happens after `sudo modprobe -v 8192cu`

Comment: I have no idea. Have you checked it works in Windows(TM) ? May be the USB key is dead. Happened to me after 5 minutes with another one. Also, what is the output of `ifconfig wlan1` ?

Comment: The kernel module simply did not build.

Comment: Is 'Enable WiFi' set in the Network Manager icon? Please tell us what about the internal device is not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your problem is. May the USB key is dead ?

If you're desperate, you could try the drivers available from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new via the PPA at https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi

This is the driver from realtek, updated and patched, with fixes.

First, **uninstall** the realtek driver (`sudo make uninstall` ? and remove blacklist file in /etc/modprobe.d). Then,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hanipouspilot/rtlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install rtl8192cu-dkms
```

Comment: But all blacklist of `rtl8192cu` should be removed to use this ppa.

Comment: Yes, that's the part about uninstalling the realtek driver.

Comment: @Pilot6 it's your PPA, right ? ;-)

Comment: Yes, it is mine.